# Component disappears immediately after I add it using onClick

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to add a component onto my App.js whenever a certain button is clicked. I've been able to do this successfully but now, as soon as I add the component the page refreshes and the component disappears. What am I doing wrong?

Heres the issue on CodeSandBox: https://codesandbox.io/s/github/JojoDuke/miCard-test?file=/src/App.js

**App.js**

```
import './App.css';
import CardItem from './Components/CardItem';
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

function App() {
  const [newCard, setNewCard] = useState([]);

  const createCard = (e) => {
    setNewCard(newCard.concat(<CardItem key={newCard.length}/>));
  }

  return (
    <div className="main">
      <div className="block">
        <h2 style={{ marginLeft: "20px", marginTop: "10px", }}>Midas</h2>
        
        <div>
            <form className="inputForm">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Name of Card"/>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Mobile Money Number"/>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Amount"/>
                <button className="card-btn" onClick={createCard}>Create Card</button>
            </form>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="cards-div">
        {newCard}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your `<button>` is inside of a form, the default click behaviour is to submit the form (see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#attr-formenctype). In order to stop the page from submitting, you'll need to add `type="button"`.